# Not able to fetch my data in the way i am sending it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code in which i am showing some notes which i send to firebase, now when i am fetching them back they are not according to the serial in which i send them,  i am getting random serial of notes.

```
 class Show_notes extends StatefulWidget {
      const Show_notes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

       @override
      _Show_notesState createState() => _Show_notesState();
      }

      class _Show_notesState extends State<Show_notes> {

      CollectionReference ref= FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('Notes');
       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Show_Notes'),
         centerTitle: true,
         flexibleSpace: Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             gradient: LinearGradient(
               colors: <Color>[
                 Colors.grey,
                 Colors.blueAccent,
                 Colors.grey,
               ]
             )
           ),
         ),
       ),
        body:SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
               future: ref.get() ,
                 builder: (context,snapshot){
                 if(snapshot.hasData){
                   return ListView.builder(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 2, 2, 2),
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      Map data= snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map;
                      DateTime mynote_time=data['Time'].toDate();
                      String formattedTime =
                      DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(mynote_time);
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Card(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 1, 3, 1),
                                  child: Text(
                                      "${data['title']}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 1, 3, 1),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "${data['description']}",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  child: Text(
                                    formattedTime
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            borderOnForeground: true,
                            shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            elevation: 10,
                          ),

                        ],
                      );
                      }
                      );
                }
                else return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(150, 200, 0, 50),
                  child: SpinKitPumpingHeart(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    size: 100,
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  ),
                );
                }),
              ],
           ),
        ),
          floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[100],
            onPressed: (){
             Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Write_Note()));
           },
           child: Icon(
             Icons.add,
             size: 20,
           ),
         ),
        ),
       floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      );
     }
   }
```

Below code is for sending my notes to Firebase

```
void addnote() async{
  CollectionReference ref= FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection("users")
     .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
     .collection('Notes');

   var data={
     'title': titletext.text,
     'description': destext.text,
     'Time': DateTime.now(),
   };
    ref.add(data);
 }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean by "serial", I guess you want your `Notes` to be retrieved sorted in the same order that you added them to the collection.

If that's the case, you need to query sorted by your `Time` field. For example:

```dart
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   future: ref.orderBy('Time', 'asc').get(),
...
```

I honestly don't know how a dart `DateTime` serializes to Firestore, so I would suggest you also change your timestamp field to an actual firestore timestamp:

```dart
var data={
     'title': titletext.text,
     'description': destext.text,
     'Time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
   };
    ref.add(data);
```